# d3.datum use a selected option value

Tags: javascript, d3.js, select

I have to make a search function with d3.js

here's the schematic diagram:

[image]

when I click the "搜尋" button, the screen would zoom in and pin at the related village.(The map is drew by d3.js)

Can I using jQuery and d3.js simultaneously?

Here's my code:

```
<body>
<div class="search-bar">
    <select class="select" id="country"></select>
    <select class="select" id="town"></select>
    <select class="select" id="village"></select>
    <div id="button3">搜尋</div>
</div>
<script>
$('#village').on('change', function () {
    var selected_village = this.value
});
var searchResult=d3.select('#button3')
    .datum({id: selected_village})
    .on("click",clicked);
</script>
</body>
```

I want to get the village select value when the select tag on change and bind to the variable "selected_village" by using datum.

Comment: You can use d3 and jQuery together, yes. If you want to bind data to `button3` when `#village` changes, you will need to move the code inside the change handler.